# Move the cursor for input text to the right

Tags: html, css

I want the the point at which a user types text into a textfield to be moved to the right *without moving the margin of the text field to the right*. I want this because the search button lies on top of the text field for styling purposes and currently when a user begins to type text it starts underneath the search button. So I need the default point of the cursor to be moved to the right by a few pixels. Is this possible with CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would definately use

```
text-indent: 20px;
```

=)

Comment: While padding may work, using text-indent is the natural solution.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is what you are looking for.

```
.search-box{padding-left: 25px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```